# Xamarin Forms CarouselView binding from viewmodel in itemsources

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using a CarouselView control with static content in it :

```
<CarouselView
            x:Name="TutorialCarousel"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type ContentView}">
                    <ContentView ... />
                    <ContentView ... />
                    <ContentView ... />
```

Inside my ContentView i have Binding for example (this is one ContentView from ItemsSource's carouselview) :

```
<ContentView>
    <Entry Text="MyValue" />
    ...
</ContentView>
```

MyValue is a property defined in a ViewModel as ContentPage's BindingContext.  But at runtime, the binding does not work at all.

Is there a way to do it?